# Simplest way to get xpath between two nodes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

With nokogiri it's easy to get the absolute path from any node back to the root by just calling `node.path`. Take this example:

```xml
<bookstore>
  <department category="COOKING">
    <book>
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book>
      <title lang="en">Nice meals</title>
      <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
  </department>
  <department category="WEB">
    <book>
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
  </department>
</bookstore>
```

If I did

```
tree.search("//title[text() = 'Learning XML']").first.path
```

I would get something like `bookstore/department[2]/book[1]/title[1]`

Now what if I wanted to get the path to this node, but instead of from the root, I wanted to get it from e.g. `//department[@category='WEB']` and all the way down to the same title node?

In other words. How can I generically get/generate the path between two known nodes like `//department[@category='WEB']` to `bookstore/department[2]/book[1]/title[1]`?

**EDIT**

I have been thinking about some way of turning the `//department[@category='WEB']` into a new kind of "root", e.g. by deleting something, and then using the `.path` method on the title node again. This doesn't seem very "simple though"...

Comment: Have you tried `tree.xpath("//department[@category='WEB']/book[1]/title[1]")` ?

Comment: Hehe, well of cause that's the result, but I want to be able to generate that result programmatically from knowing the two nodes //department[@category='WEB'] and bookstore/department[2]/book[1]/title[1]

Comment: Since you always have the same structure, `"//department[@category='WEB']/" + "bookstore/department[2]/book[1]/title[1]".split("/").drop(2).join("/")`

Comment: Is one element always the parent of the other?

Comment: The above is just a simple example. The structure can be completely different. The only thing I ALWAYS know is a path to each of the two nodes. I just want to know the path in-between the two.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not wild about the string-based hack at the end, but now this produces clean XPaths:

```
require 'nokogiri'
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def path_to( node )
    self_ancestors = [self].concat(self.ancestors)
    shared = (self_ancestors & [node].concat(node.ancestors)).first
    [ "../"*self_ancestors.index(shared),
      ".", node.path[shared.path.length..-1] ]
      .join
      .sub( %r{\A\./|/\.(?=/|\z)}, '' ) # remove superfluous "."
  end
end

doc = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read('tmp.rxml'))
n1  = doc.at("//department[@category='WEB']")
n2  = doc.at("//title[.='Learning XML']")
n3  = doc.at("//year[.='2003']")
n4  = doc.at("//@lang")

p n1.path_to(n2) #=> "book/title"
p n2.path_to(n3) #=> "../year"
p n3.path_to(n2) #=> "../title"
p n2.path_to(n1) #=> "../.."
p n1.path_to(n1) #=> "."
p n4.path_to(n2) #=> "../../../../department[2]/book/title"
p n2.path_to(n4) #=> "../../../department[1]/book[1]/title/@lang"

p n2.at( n2.path_to(n4) )==n4 #=> true
```

Comment: Hmm quite smart, However I really wan't it to be using the element names instead of "any" element - like the "path" method does.

Comment: @NielsKristian Your specifications are vague. Please supply an exact example of the output you want, combined with at least one or two sample inputs/nodes that should create the output. The XPath above *does* use the `path` command, except where it uses `..` (which is unambiguous) or `.` (which is also unambiguous). The only thing 'unclean' about the XPath is the superfluous presence of `"."`, a basic no-op.

Comment: There, I've edited the method to create clean output. As noted in the answer, I'd like to find a cleaner way to remove the `.` (like, by not creating them unless necessary) but that's just purist desires.